# BeanShell PostProcessor in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have code in BeanShell PostProcessor like this,

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import java.util.*;
```

> ```
> String response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
> JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
> JSONArray GroupList = (JSONArray) parser.parse(response);
> JSONArray GroupIds = new JSONArray();
> while (i.hasNext()) 
> {
> JSONObject objGroup = (JSONObject) i.next();
>   GroupIds.push(i.next().get("id"));
>   var.put("GroupIds",GroupIds);
> }
>
> log.info(GroupIds);
> ```

When I try to run test, it show error,

> jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method:
>   eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import
>   org.json.simple.JSONObject; import org.json.simple.JSONArray; import
>   org. . . . '' : Attempt to resolve method: hasNext() on undefined
>   variable or class name: i
>
> jmeter.extractor.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script
>   org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method:
>   eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import
>   org.json.simple.JSONObject; import org.json.simple.JSONArray; import
>   org. . . . '' : Attempt to resolve method: hasNext() on undefined
>   variable or class name: i

How can I correct this code ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong , you have :

> while (i.hasNext())

But i is not defined.

You should add something like this before the while:

> Iterator i = GroupList.iterator();

Comment: in jmeter/lib, I have a json-simple-1.1.1.jar

Comment: and it have new error this: jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.json.simple.JSONObject; import org.json.simple.JSONArray; import org. . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Cannot access field: iterator, on object:

Comment: Can you open a new question and show the log either in pastebin or using ">" in stackoverflow so that it shows clearly